# PuTTY redirect http to https

Tags: putty, http, https, headers

I am trying to make a simple GET request to [www.delek.co.il/stations](http://www.delek.co.il/stations) using PuTTY

[image]

And the header:

> ```
> GET /stations HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.delek.co.il
> ```

And I am getting HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
content-type: text/html
content-length: 707
date: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 22:28:36 GMT
server: LiteSpeed
location: https://www.delek.co.il/stations
x-content-type-options: nosniff

<!DOCTYPE html>
           <html style="height:100%">
                                     <head>
                                           <meta name="viewport" content="wi             dth=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
                                                   <title> 301 Moved Permane         ntly
</title></head>
           <body style="color: #444; margin:0;font: normal 14px/20px Arial,          Helvetica, sans-serif; height:100%; background-color: #fff;">
                                                         <div style="height:             auto; min-height:100%; ">     <div style="text-align: center; width:800px; margi     n-        left: -400px; position:absolute; top: 30%; left:50%;">
                                                            <h1 style="margi             n:0; font-size:150px; line-height:150px; font-weight:bold;">301</h1>
                                                                <h2 style="m             argin-top:20px;font-size: 30px;">Moved Permanently
</h2>
 <p>The document has been permanently moved.</p>
                                                </div></div></body></html>
```

How can I make a new call to the https redirected site (**location:https://www.delek.co.il/stations**) using PuTTY? What is the right header parameters for that?

Comment: **PuTTY doesn't do SSL/TLS**, and no one can do it by hand. On Windows, try curl[.exe] (now standard in Win10), powershell invoke-webrequest (which is _aliased_ as curl; to use the curl program specify .exe), or vbscript xmlhttprequest; or get OpenSSL -- I recommend http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html -- and use `openssl s_client`. If you really want you can get https://www.stunnel.org/downloads.html (which embeds OpenSSL), run it in client=yes mode, and use PuTTY to do HTTP to the stunnel local port which is relayed to the remote as HTTPS.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for the explanation